# Your app information could not be saved while uploading to app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I want to upload a new app. I've upload a build, added it to version information, saved it. Everything was fine. When i press "Submit for review" it says **"Your app information could not be saved. Try again"**. I've tried again many times, but problem is still not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

One of the following solutions will work:

1. Log out of iTunes Connect and clear your cookies and website data. Then Log back into iTunes Connect and check if the issue has been resolved.
2. If you are using safari then try updating it to its new version.
3. Switch to another browser.

Answer (score 0):

If all metadata you  filled correctly then Apple server might be busy you can try after some time.